# Sharing code between GAEJ and Android projects

Tags: android, google-app-engine

In Eclipse:
Is it possible to Sharing code between GAEJ and Android projects? And or GAEJ and another GAEJ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there was a nice talk about GAE & Android integration on the last GoogleIO 2012:

[Google I_O 2012 - Building Mobile App Engine Backends for Android, iOS and the Web](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4)

they show how to use same data structures for data exchange between Android and GAE.

Answer (score 1):

If you asking about how to set it up in Eclipse, I use the 'linked source' option in the source tab of Java Build Path.  Here's a blog post with details:
http://blog.christoffer.me/2011/01/sharing-code-between-multiple-java.html

If you are asking about whether it is practical - from the code perspective - that is trickier.

When trying to share Android code with GAE/J I discovered that I had dependencies on android packages, e.g. android.util.Base64.  Sharing code means dropping stuff like this and using 3rd party libraries instead.  For example, the Guava library works on GAE/J and Android:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Logging is another problem.  My GAE/J code was writing to java.util.logging.Logger, whereas my Android code ultimately logs to 'android.util.Log.println.  If you use a common library framework like log4j or just writing to System.Out I think you will lose functionality in the log viewer - ideally you would have a logging library or shim that mapped to java.util.logging.Logger or android.util.Log.println depending on the platform.